# How to create nested dictionary from strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string related to a programs output, now I need to convert the string into a dictionary. I have tried it by using `dict()` and `zip()` commands but I am not able to fetch the results.

This is the code I have so far:

```
string = "Eth1/1 vlan-1 typemode-eth status:access eth1/2 vlan-1 type-eth status:access"
list1=string.split(' ')
 print(list1)
['Eth1/1', 'vlan-1', 'typemode-access']
```

and further than this I have no idea:

```
{'eth1/1': {'Speed': '10Gb', 'Vlan': 1, 'Type Mode': 'eth', 'status': 'access'}, 'eth1/2': {'Speed': '10Gb', 'Vlan': 1, 'Type Mode': 'eth', 'status': 'access'}}
```

Comment: dict is a key:value pairs - you have to decide what will be what in your list - split accordingly, assign accordingly

Comment: string1= "speed vlan status reason" are the keys and string1="10gbps 1 acess none " are the values

Answer (score 0):

From your result to get a value see the following example. See inline comments.

```py
import re

result = {}

string = "Eth1/1 vlan-1 typemode-eth status:access eth1/2 vlan-1 type-eth status:access"

a = re.search('access', string)  # this gives 2 positions for the word access.

list1 = [string[0:a[0]], string[[a[0]+1]:]]   # two substrings. a[0] is used to get 
        # roughly the middle of the string where the spplitpoint is of both
        # substrings. Using access as key word gives flexibility if there is a third
        # substring as well.

result = dict(list1)  # result should be same as result2.

#            y1         z1 
result2 = {'eth1/1': {'Speed': '10Gb', 'Vlan': 1, 'Type Mode': 'eth', 'status': 'access'},
           'eth1/2': {'Speed': '10Gb', 'Vlan': 1, 'Type Mode': 'eth', 'status': 'access'}}
#            y2 = eth1/2.

#             y1        y2
x = result['eth1/1']['Speed']   # replace any word at y1 or z1 to fetch another result.

print ('Got x : %s' % x)   # this prints '10Gb'.
```

Basically what you've created is nested dictionaries. So addressing y1 first is enabling to get data from that particular dictionary. after y1 calling for z1 is getting the value from that particular key inside your first nested dictionary. If you change the keywords at x you get different different values back (regardless that it looks the same in your example; ttry with different values to see the result). Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the idea given here. But can you please tell me how to create the result as output

Comment: fixed. I left the second result there so you can check yourself to see how its done. The coords might need a little finetuning by adding integers or subtract but you get the hang of it I bet!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
string = "Eth1/1 vlan-1 typemode-eth status:access eth1/2 vlan-1 type-eth status:access eth1/3 vlan-1 type-eth status:access"

strList = string.split(" ")

indexPos = []

for data in range(0,len(strList)):
   if strList[data].lower()[0:3] == 'eth':
     print('Found',data)
     indexPos.append(data)

dataDict = dict()
for i in range(0,len(indexPos)):
   stringDict = dict()
   stringDict['Speed'] = '10Gb' 
   if i is not len(indexPos)-1:
      string = strList[indexPos[i]:indexPos[i+1]]
   else:
      string = strList[indexPos[i]:]

   for i in range(0,len(string)):
      if i is not 0:
         if i is not 3:
            valueSplit = string[i].split('-')
         else:
            print(i)
            valueSplit = string[i].split(':')

        stringDict[valueSplit[0]] = valueSplit[1] 
   dataDict[string[0]] = stringDict
```

I have written this code according the pattern in code. Please let me know if it work for you.

Comment: I want the result to be a dictionary from the given string  not the count of words

Comment: Output of above is data dictionary : {'Eth1/1': {'Speed': '10Gb',
  'vlan': '1',
  'typemode': 'eth',
  'status': 'access'},
 'eth1/2': {'Speed': '10Gb', 'vlan': '1', 'type': 'eth', 'status': 'access'},
 'eth1/3': {'Speed': '10Gb', 'vlan': '1', 'type': 'eth', 'status': 'access'}}                                    print(dataDict)